How to change default ubuntu titlebar icons and border-radius
I would like to alter the Yaru GTK theme code to make the window title bars have rectangular window borders, instead of the default rounded-rectangle shape. Additionally I would like to change the window icons to be squares instead of circles (I assume that can be done editing the icons with GIMP, Inkscape, etc.) so please tell me where the yaru icon directory location is.

How do I make the titlebar have squared edges instead of rounded edges?
Where are the Yaru icon files/folders located?

titlebar:

